# Alignment issue in High chart's bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, alignment

[image: Chart]

I am creating this bar chart using high charts. The alignment of the bar is not in the middle of section(like first red bar is not in middle of the Jan, 2016). Is there any option to place all bars in middle of each sections?

Comment: without code it is difficult to help, anyways check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/

Comment: @Deep3015 https://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/2751/ please see this demo.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for the issue.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.5,
        borderWidth: 2 ,
        groupPadding: .5                
    }
}
```